# Detect color of font in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, web-crawler

I am currently building a crawler in Excel with VBA to crawl table data from a public website with the help from several references available online.

However, I need an extra step where I need to recognize the color of the font used in the fonts that I crawl.

For example: If some of the words are in red color while the rest are in black, I will be able to identify them. How can I detect the font colour?

Below is part of my code.

```
For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
            tabno = tabno + 1
            If tabno = 5 Then
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)
            rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
            For Each rw In tbl.Rows
                If count = 1 Then
                For Each cl In rw.Cells
                    rng.Value = cl.outerText
                    Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                    i = i + 1
                Next cl
                nextrow = nextrow + 1
                Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -i)
                i = 0
                End If
                count = count + 1
            Next rw
            End If
        Next tbl
```

Comment: point out the error in your code. what is not working? what have you tried?

Comment: Hi mehow, my code are working fine. What i need to find out is how to let VBA recognise the font color used in the IE. :)

Comment: so what have you tried

Comment: Do you mean text within the <td>? Can you show some example html

Comment: hi all, thanks for the interest. the text in the html is in a table form, or <table>, where one of the data in the row, or <tr><td>, has a different font color from the rest. ie, <td align = 'center' ><font color='red'>sample text</font></td>. i have no idea how to let VBA recognise the color of the font that it crawls.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the the font element is always the first and only element within the cell you care about you could;

```
Dim clr As String

For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
    For Each rw In tbl.Rows
        For Each cl In rw.Cells
           ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
           ActiveCell.Value = cl.outerText

            If Not IsNull(cl.FirstChild.GetAttribute("color")) Then
               ActiveCell.Font.Color = toRgb(cl.FirstChild.GetAttribute("color"))
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next

...

Function toRgb(hx As String) As Long
    Dim r As Long, g As Long, b As Long
    r = Val("&H" & Mid$(hx, 2, 2))
    g = Val("&H" & Mid$(hx, 4, 2))
    b = Val("&H" & Mid$(hx, 6, 2))
    toRgb = RGB(r, g, b)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Alex K., i tried your codes but seem to encounter an error:

Run-time error "438":
Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the interest and help by some of you. greatly appreciated.

I have done a work-around by crawling the "source codes" from the HTML page and substringed the value in the table to what i want to distinguish.

Below are the work-around that i did:

```
rng.Value = cl.outerText
temp = cl.outerHTML
If InStr(temp, "color=") <> 0 Then
rng.Value = rng.Value + " *this value has a different font color from the rest"
End If
```

Regards.